# what does :* stand for in ruby

Tags: ruby

I recently came across this code

```
left_params  = [:*]*2
right_params = [:*]*2  
t[*left_params] = self[*right_params]
```

where t expects 2 integer arguments. I couldn't figure out what this was supposed to do.

Comment: It's impossible to explain why it's being used in the code you've posted, based on the complete lack of context, but it's effectively doing `t[:*, :*] = self[:*, :*]`.

Answer (score 3):

It's a symbol. Like `"*".to_sym`.

Comment: but shouldn't that throw an error you are passing a symbol instead of an integer?

Comment: Why would it? Did you program it to do so? Nothing about what you've posted can help us answer that question.

Comment: To put it another way, we don't know what `t` and `self` are. If they are Arrays, then yes it would throw an error. If they're Hashes or something, then no.

Comment: @Satya Actually, even if they were hashes, it would throw an error. It's being indexed with two arguments, `t[:*, :*]`, which would throw an error for a hash.

Answer (score 2):

It's a symbol wrapped in an array.

The code works because arrays support multiplication in Ruby. E.g.

```
list = ["hello", "world"]
multiplied_list = list * 2
=> ["hello", "world", "hello", "world"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[:*]*2
```

create an array with double star simbols(`[:*, :*]`)

```
t[*left_params] = self[*right_params]
```

`*` here mean unpack array, so this is interpreted `t[:*, :*] = self[:*, :*]`. Without `*` sign expression would be interpreted like `t[[:*, :*]] = self[[:*, :*]]`